# decryption password in PHP not working

Tags: php

i am new all around PHP development. i am trying to encrypt the password into DB and decryption  it in the opposite way but for some reason i am not get the correct value in decryption.
for example i insert the password : "mat1234" when i decryption it i got:
"6mF34vv0wUBREjdV9S2ZgfCNk+wwMWZkMjFjZTkx"
please help me to resolve it.

this is my main php code:

test.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matant
 * Date: 5/13/2015
 * Time: 1:29 PM
 */
error_reporting(0);
//ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

require_once 'index.php';
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$user = $_POST['paramUsername'];
$password = $_POST['paramPassword'];
$email = $_POST['paramEmail'];
$output = array();
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con)
{
    die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('api',$con);
$fn = new Functions();

if($tag == "login")
{
    $encrypted_password = md5($password);
    $output["encrypted_password"] = $encrypted_password;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.usern ='$user' and users.password ='$encrypted_password'");
    if(!$result){
        $output["error_msg"] = "query failed";
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($no_of_rows > 0){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                $output["user"] = $row;
                $output["msg"]="working";
                print(json_encode($output));
        }


    else{
        $output["msg"]="Password or user is incorrect!";
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}
elseif($tag == "insert")
{

   /* $hash = $fn->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"];
    $salt = $hash["salt"];*/
    $encrypted_password = md5($password);
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (usern , email , password) VALUES ('$user' , '$email' , '$encrypted_password')");
    if(!$result)
    {
        $output["msg"] = "failed";
        $output["error_msg"] = "insert failed";
        print(json_encode($output));
    }else{
        $output["msg"] = "insert working";
        print(json_encode($output));
    }

}
else {
    $output["msg"] = "not working";
    $output["error_msg"] = "tag param is missing";
    print(json_encode($output));
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but you cannot decrypt a hash.

Comment: The point here is that you're not supposed to decrypt it, and PHP has functions already made for this called `password_hash` and `password_verify`, there's no need to roll your own.

Comment: You should never be able to decrypt your users passwords...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be able to reverse a hash, that is the point of a hash; it is a one way cryptographic function. You can remake it and it is exactly the same, but you cannot reverse it without knowing the original password first.

You shouldn't really be homebrewing your own crypto (e.g. you need to think about things like salting); therefore using a pre-made hashing algorithm like Bcrypt or PBKDF2 is recommended.

In newer PHP versions there are password_hash and password_verify functions for helping you handle passwords.